# Unable to broadcast to SignalR Clients from server code (outside of Hub)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, autofac

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 on .NET 4.8. There are 2 projects, one is for the SignalR Hub and related resources, the other project is the main application. The SignalR project is configured as a virtual directory under the main application.

The hub works, I think. My clients are able to connect to the hub and start a connection. They can call server functions in the hub.

Likewise, the server hub is able to broadcast to a single client or all clients.

The problem is that I can't seem to broadcast anything from outside of the hub. For example, when a new action occurs in the main application I want to broadcast a message to all connected clients. That part does not work no matter how I approach it.

Both projects are using Autofac with OWIN. Here is the relevant code:

SignalR Hub:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DSOps.Web.Dispatcher.Code;
using log4net;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace DSOps.Web.Dispatcher.Hubs
{
    [HubName("controlhub")]
    public class DispatcherHub : Hub, IDispatcherHub
    {
        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DispatcherHub));

        public static readonly List<string> ConnectedClients = new List<string>();
        private static readonly object LockObject = new object();

        public DispatcherHub()
        {
            _log.Debug("Parameterless ...");
            Initialize();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            _log.Debug("Initialization ...");
        }

        // Method for handling ping requests from the client to keep the connection alive
        [HubMethodName("ping")]
        public async Task Ping()
        {
            _log.Debug("Received ping from client.");

            await Clients.Caller.pingResponse("Pong!"); // Sends a "pingResponse" message to calling client
        
            //await UpdateLeadsAsync();
        }
    
        [HubMethodName("send")]
        public async Task Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            _log.Debug($"Received message from client: {message}");
            await Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

        [HubMethodName("updateLeads")]
        public async Task UpdateLeadsAsync(int leadsCount = 0)
        {
            _log.Debug($"Received lead count: {leadsCount}");

            //var leadCount = await _svc.GetLeadCount();
            //if (leadCount > 0) 
            await Clients.Caller.updateLeads(leadsCount);
        }

        [HubMethodName("jobCreated")]
        public Task JobCreatedAsync(int jobId)
        {
            _log.Debug($"Job Created: {jobId}");

             return Clients.All.jobCreated(jobId);
        }

        #region SignalR

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            _log.Debug("Client reconnected.");
            return base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            lock (LockObject)
            {
                ConnectedClients.Add(connectionId);
                _log.Debug($"Client connected. ConnectionId: {connectionId}");
                LogConnectedClients();
            }

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            lock (LockObject)
            {
                ConnectedClients.Remove(connectionId);
                _log.Debug($"Client disconnected. ConnectionId: {connectionId}");
                LogConnectedClients();
            }

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        } 

        private void LogConnectedClients()
        {
            _log.Debug($"Connected clients: {string.Join(", ", ConnectedClients)}");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is `IDispatcherHub` which is bland for now:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DSOps.Web.Dispatcher.Code
{
    public interface IDispatcherHub
    {
        Task JobCreatedAsync(int jobId);
    }
}
```

Here is the main application dependency registrations:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Initialize Autofac container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register log4net logger
        builder.Register(c => LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DSOps.Web.Controllers.HomeController)))
            .As<ILog>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // ... other registrations

        // Enable diagnostic logging
        builder.RegisterBuildCallback(c =>
        {
            var log = c.Resolve<ILog>();
            log.Debug("Container built.");

            // Output registration information to log
            foreach (var registration in c.ComponentRegistry.Registrations)
            {
                log.Debug($"Registered: {registration.Activator.LimitType}");
            }
        });

        // Configure log4net
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        // MVC Configuration
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // Register controllers with Autofac
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        // Register the IOwinContext
        builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()).As<IOwinContext>();

        // Register DSOps.Core.DSOpsService as a singleton
        builder.RegisterType<DSOpsService>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        // Inside Autofac configuration in the Startup class
        builder.Register(c => new DefaultDependencyResolver())
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => new ConnectionManager(c.Resolve<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>()))
            .As<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.IConnectionManager>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // Register Twilio-related services
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            return new TwilioMessagingService(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioUsername"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioPassword"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioOriginPhoneNumber"]
            );
        }).As<IMessagingService>().SingleInstance();

        // Register SignalR hubs
        builder.RegisterHubs(typeof(DispatcherHub).Assembly).SingleInstance();

        // Build the Autofac container
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Set Autofac as the dependency resolver for MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        // OWIN SIGNALR SETUP
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac
            Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container),
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        };

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the standard SignalR middleware
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        // Map SignalR to a specific URL (e.g., "/signalr") and configure the HubConfiguration
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);

        // Output registrations to the console for debugging
        ContainerInspector.InspectContainer(container);
    }
}
```

SignalR project dependency registrations:

```
public class Startup1
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            // Initialize Autofac container
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register your services, hubs, and other dependencies with builder
            builder.RegisterHubs(typeof(DispatcherHub).Assembly).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // Register IHubContext<DispatcherHub>
            builder.Register(c =>
            {
                //var hubConfiguration = c.Resolve<HubConfiguration>();
                return GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<DispatcherHub>(null);
            }).As<IHubContext<DispatcherHub>>().InstancePerRequest();

            // Build the Autofac container
            var container = builder.Build();

            // Set Autofac as the dependency resolver for MVC
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

            // OWIN SIGNALR SETUP:
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
                Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container),
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };

            // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the standard SignalR middleware.
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

            // Map SignalR to a specific URL (e.g., "/signalr") and configure the HubConfiguration.
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);

            // Output registrations to the console for debugging
            ContainerInspector.InspectContainer(container);
        }
    }
```

Client JS:

```
var ds_LeadTabId = "#ui-id-5";
var ds_PingInterval = 60000;
var ds_PulseInterval = 3000;
var intervalId = 0;

// Configure SignalR connection
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.url = "/admin/dispatcher/signalr";
$.connection.hub.stateChanged(function(change) {
    console.log("SignalR Connection State: " + change.newState);
});

// Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
var chat = $.connection.controlhub;

// Function to send a ping message to keep the connection alive
function sendPing() {
    if ($.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
        chat.server.ping();
    }
}

// Function to play a notification sound based on the event
function playNotificationSound(eventType) {
    var isMuted = document.getElementById('btnMute').getAttribute("data-muted") === "true";

    if (!isMuted) {
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = getSoundSource(eventType);
        audio.play();
    }
}

// Function to get the sound source based on the event type
function getSoundSource(eventType) {
    switch (eventType) {
    case 'broadcastMessage':
        return '/Admin/Dispatcher/Content/Sounds/426594__mootmcnoodles__ding.wav';
    case 'updateLeads':
        return '/Admin/Dispatcher/Content/Sounds/455197__matrixxx__retro-bird-04.wav';
    case 'jobCreated':
        return '/Admin/Dispatcher/Content/Sounds/209578__zott820__cash-register-purchase.wav';
    default:
        return '/Admin/Dispatcher/Content/Sounds/27568__suonho__memorymoon_space-blaster-plays.wav';
    }
}

// Function to start the hub and set up event handlers
function startHubConnection() {
    if ($.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
        return;
    }

    console.log("Starting Hub.");
    $.connection.hub.start({ shouldSubscribe: true })
        .done(function() {
            if (intervalId !== 0) clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(sendPing, ds_PingInterval);
            $('#btnSendBroadcast').click(sendMessageIfConnected);
        })
        .fail(function(e) {
            alert(e);
        });
}

// Function to send a message if the connection is open
function sendMessageIfConnected() {
    if ($.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.connected && $('#message').val() !== "") {
        chat.server.send(username, $('#message').val());
        $('#message').val('').focus();
    }
}

// Start the connection.
startHubConnection();

// Event handlers
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function(name, message) {
    var messageHistoryTextarea = document.getElementById("discussion");
    messageHistoryTextarea.value += name + ": " + message + "\n";
    messageHistoryTextarea.scrollTop = messageHistoryTextarea.scrollHeight;
    playNotificationSound('broadcastMessage');
};

chat.client.writeConsole = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
};

chat.client.updateLeads = function(leadsCount) {
    console.log("updateLeads received " + leadsCount);
    if (leadsCount > 0) {
        $(ds_LeadTabId).parent().addClass("has-badge");
        $(".has-badge .my-badge").html(leadsCount);
        $("form#searchLeads button[type='submit']").click();
        playNotificationSound('updateLeads');
    } else {
        $(".has-badge .my-badge").html("");
        $(ds_LeadTabId).parent().removeClass("has-badge");
    }
};

chat.client.jobCreated = function(jobId) {
    console.log("jobCreated " + jobId);
    playNotificationSound('jobCreated');
};

chat.client.pingResponse = function(message) {
    console.log("Received ping response: " + message);
};

// Connect to the SignalR hub
var connection = $.hubConnection("/admin/dispatcher/signalr");
var hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('controlhub');

// Start the connection
connection.start().done(function() {
    // You can invoke SignalR methods here if needed
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.error('SignalR connection error:', error);
});
```

All of the above code would appear to be working, but in my main application I have the following function that does not work:

```
    public async Task NotifyUpdates()
    {
        try
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DispatcherHub>();

            if (hubContext != null)
            {
                await hubContext.Clients.All.jobCreated(1234);
                _log.Debug("NotifyUpdates method executed.");
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Warn("Hub context is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("Exception in NotifyUpdates method", ex);
        }
    }
```

hubContext appears to be resolved, jobCreated(1234) line of code executes with no errors. But SignalR doesn't output anything in Chrome's console. Log4net doesn't output anything. The connected clients never seem to receive anything. NotifyUpdates() runs with a Log4net entry of `NotifyUpdates method executed.`, but absolutely no trace in any log/console of SignalR/Hub activity.

My suspicion is that hubContext doesn't have a valid list of connected clients, but I don't know how to fix it. I also suspect that the problem is how I'm registering one or more dependencies. I've experimented, but haven't found the right combination amidst conflicting documentation - re: AutoFac/OWIN/SignalR.

Can anyone point me on how to get NotifyUpdates to work from a main application Controller?

==[ EDIT ]==============================

Per recommendation, I did move the SignalR code to the main project. startup1 is no longer.

But I have the same issue. The clients are able to connect to the hub, call hub server methods, and the server hub is able to call client methods. All of the server logs and browser console look perfect. No problems.

NotifyUpdates() resolves the hubContext and executes jobCreated(1234) with no error. No server error, no browser console error, nothing. The hub server method breakpoint does not get hit and neither does the breakpoint in the client method. Essentially, calling NotifyUpdates() outputs `NotifyUpdates method executed.` to the server log. It has not other effect that I can see.

Comment: `public static readonly List<string> ConnectedClients = new List<string>();` <-- This won't work outside of a limited, toy, examples (e.g. it definitely won't work on a multi-instance web-farm...)

Comment: _"The SignalR project is configured as a virtual directory under the main application."_ <-- **That's your problem**: SignalR needs to be in _the same_ application. (IIS Application Scopes represent isolation boundaries between applications' server-side code: they don't share anything - even if they run in the same `w3wp.exe` instance they'll be in entirely separate AppDomains).

Comment: It's only for debugging purposes right now. I don't rely on it for anything except showing a list of connected clients from within the Hub.

Comment: @Dai Really? I thought it would be good practice to put the SignalR code in its own project. The main project runs at /admin and the SignalR project is a virtual directory at /admin/dispatcher - can you tell me more?

Comment: No, it's not good-practice at all...  SignalR's `IHubContext` service's implementation (`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubContext`) relies on being able to access SignalR's internal data/structures/etc which is only possible when it's in the same AppDomain (**or** you're using a correctly configured Backplane)

Comment: I see. So my connection URL should be /admin/signalr instead of /admin/dispatcher/signalr?

Comment: Yes, but you should consolidate your work _first_ before reconfiguring things.

Comment: @Dai I moved the Signalr project code into my main application. Still it is working for clients to connect and call server hub methods, and the hub server call client methods. I'm 100% sure the hub is working and clients are connected, but still unable to broadcast to clients or call server hub methods from a Controller method. No errors, no log/console activity. Same problem as described in my original question. :S

Comment: Honestly there's 1,001+ possible reasons for that to be happening and it's not something anyone can really diagnose from an SO post. I can only suggest creating a new empty ASP.NET+SignalR project and getting that to work, then playing spot-the-difference with your current system.